# Finding the maximum number of equidistant points on a line segment

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

Given a set of points on a straight line segment. The points may lie anywhere on the line. I need an aglorithm to find the maximum number of points that lie on the line at regular intervals.

eg on a straight line denoted by y = 0, I may have some points like :

```
[3,0], [1,0], [4,0], [7,0],[11,0], [10,0]

Output : 4 
     [1,0] , [4,0], [7,0], [10,0]
```

Example 2:

```
[2,1], [2,5], [2,3], [2,7], [2,6]

Output: 4
    [2,1], [2,3],[2,5], [2,7]
```

[Note: the line may have any slope. I need only a sketch of the algorithm. The points may be considered to be stored in a 2-D matrix]
please help.

Comment: There is a very obvious naive algorithm for this. Are you fine with that or do you need something particularly efficient?

Comment: You could definitely put forth the idea, we can build on it and try and optimize it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute-force algorithm in pseudo-code:

```
for each point X
  for each point Y != X
    find number of connected points from X using the distance between X and Y
  next Y
next X
```

How to find number of connected points from X using the distance between X and Y:

```
dXY = Y - X
i = 0
while point_exists(X + i * dXY)
  i = i + 1
end while
```

Comment: I guess its going to exhibit exponential time complexity(due to the while loop)

Comment: the complexity should be quadratic or cubic (depending on how the innermost counting is implemented), but polynomial in all cases.

Comment: The outer two for loops make it N^2. The inner while loop, for each i, tries to find a point that is at a distance of (i*dXY) from X, so the complexity for the while loop may be O(N^2). Hence overall complexity O(N^4) ?

Comment: One thing : dXY = Y - X should have the appropriate negative or positive sign(depending on whether Y is on the left of X or on the right of X or top or below x).

Comment: The while loop is O(N^2) worst case. X + i * dXY is a specific point. Checking the existance of a point in a set is not costlier than O(N).

Comment: @letsc You don't need to bother with the sign of dXY. Even if you only look in one direction you will find the correct maximum when you are processing the end points of the longest chain.

Answer (score 0):

Choose one coordinate with non-zero (or just wider) range (e.g. X for the first example) and sort your set by this coordinate. Then find *Longest Arithmetic Progression*